# playing videos in epub

Tags: video, epub, adobe-indesign

Can I embed and play videos from an indesign cc exported .epub in

- ibooks
- kindle software (pc/mac)
- any online resource?

I want to create an epub but want as wide an audience to see it as possible.

Comment: Please clarify "Any online resource": list the actual platforms you are thinking of/aiming to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple iBooks can reproduce videos embedded into the EPUB container (or even external videos, if the corresponding property is set in the OPF manifest). See: http://www.pigsgourdsandwikis.com/2013/05/linking-to-external-video-and-audio-in.html

Kindle software for Mac (not sure for PC), can play embedded videos too, but there are more restrictions, please consult the Kindle Publishing Guidelines: http://kindlegen.s3.amazonaws.com/AmazonKindlePublishingGuidelines.pdf
(currently, Section 6 - Audio and Video Guidelines)